# Find the pixel of center of a circle in an image

Tags: python, computer-vision, centroid

Hy guys,
I need to find the coordinates of the center of the small circles inside in an image.
I don't want to use the Hought method of cv.
Every circle has radius of 20 pixels.

The image is like this:

[image]

I read the image in grayscale because I want e value normalized between 0-255.

This is the code, I can't find where I wrong:

```
img = cv2.imread('input_image',0)#read in grayscale
lista = []
rows,cols = img.shape
for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(cols):
        k = img[i,j]
        if k == 0:
            #No circle
            continue
        else:
            #Circle
            x=i+10
            y=j
            k = img[x,y]#centro del pallino
            i+=21
            
            arr = np.array([x,y,k])
            lista.append(arr)
      
print(lista)
```

I would to have a list of arrays, where each arrays contains the x coordinate, the y coordinate and the value of pixel.
Where i wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Since the top most point of the circle will be encountered for the first time in the for-loop, x and y values should be updated as `x=i` and `y = j+10`.

Also, this logic would not work if there were two circles such that the line joining centers of the two circles is nearly horizontal.